# how to run javascript setInterval on server using cpanel

Tags: javascript, php, cron, cpanel

I have following code which i wanted to run on my cpanel server using cron job but i am getting simply code to my email no database is updating. Here is code which i wanted to run on cpanel server using cron job.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = setInterval(function(){getElement()},5000);

 function getElement(){

    var links= $("#frametest").contents().find(".dharam_festival_list li .right h3 a");
    var hrefs = [];
    var headlines = [];
    links.each(function(){hrefs.push($(this).attr("href"));});
    links.each(function(){headlines.push($(this).text());});
    for(var i=0;i<hrefs.length;i++)
    {
         $.post('/insert_link/insert_amar.php', {link_address: hrefs[i], amar_heading: headlines[i]},function(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#message").hide();$("#message").fadeIn(1500);});
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="frametest" id="frametest" src="/echo/amar.php" ></iframe>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If there is another way to do this please explain that way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the wrong approach. Generally speaking, JavaScript "runs" on the client (e.g., web browser), not on the server. E-mail clients block or restrict JavaScript for security reasons.

Comment: Is there any way you know...

Comment: please guys help me i need to fix this issue urgently.

Comment: You need your code to run on the server instead of inside your e-mail client. Perhaps the easiest way to do that with a standard shared cPanel hosting account is to use PHP instead of JavaScript, then use a cron job to execute the PHP script. There are many other options, but PHP is probably already configured on your server.

Comment: I am not running in email i am running this php script using cron job but i think in cron job setInterval is not working.

Comment: this script isn't going to work because JS is client side and the cron job is executed server side...

Comment: Is there any way by which you can help me

Comment: guys don't show cold reaction please help

Comment: @user3245779 What you posted above isn't PHP, it's just an HTML page with some JavaScript. Your cPanel server can't "run" HTML as a cron job.

Comment: @user113215 Is there any way to do this

Comment: Get rid of all the HTML and javascript. These are run in the browser, this will not run in a browser if its being run by a cronjob. It looks like you are trying to extract something from a live page, if so lookup: "screen scraping" and "php"... Actually: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ That MIGHT be what you are after.

As for setInterval, again, its client side but even that aside, if you need a timed event, and you are already using cron, why not stick with cron??

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 8 years down the line and I actually encountered this problem yesterday, when I came to search, I found that this has been left open, with a little more research, I did find a solution.

This will work for PHP developers only at the moment but the same concept can be applied to any other language.

Javascript setInterval is a client-side script and won't run on the server, so you need a server script to run a cron script.

///SOLUTION///
(PHP)
PHP has a usleep() function, it's inbuilt and you need no installation. This function receives time in milliseconds as the only parameter

So, create a function to either call the function or just add in the function what you need to be done, at the end before closing the function, call usleep(givetimeinmilliseconds) then call the function you just created as you close. Sample below.

In case you need to update database time after 1 second, the cron job allows only 1-minute calls as the least time in shared hosting.

So, the Sample code

```
<?php
//Provide what you want  updated from db
function updateTime(){
//code or function to execute immediately
usleep(100000);
updateTime();
}
?>
```

The above is simple but very powerful. In case you have tried and failed, make me know so I can provide you with a working sample.